# Migrate an AndroidTV application to a phone

Tags: android-tv

Is there any process, workaround, tutorial or anything to migrate an androidTV application to a phone?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I only see examples and tutorials on installing mobile app to AndroidTV. You can check it in this thread: [Installing android mobile apps on android TV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39934595/installing-android-mobile-apps-on-android-tv)

> Perhaps the single most important thing in your manifest would be
>
> ```
> <manifest>
>     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
>               android:required="false" />
>     ...
> </manifest>
> ```
>
> to allow the APK to be installed on TV.
>
> Then you can deal with other subject mentioned in the comments as `LEANBACK_LAUNCHER`.

You need to program separate mobile apps for TV and phone devices.